# how to handle connection failure in case of activeMq tcp failover

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am using activeMQ tcp failover connection and creating a consumer and subscribing to a topic produced by a producer.
Now how do I manage network failure?  If the connection between broker and client is down, how do I know when the connection is established again?
Also, how do I know whether the producer is up and running?  In case of producer restarting; how do I know about it, so that I can resubscribe the topics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with FailoverTransport you do not have to manage reconnections, he will try to reconnect indefinetly unless you specify a maxReconnectAttempts

resubscribe to the topic if the producer restart ?? not needed since your consumer is connected he dont have to care of producer

even if not needed, to be notified on FailoverTransport state changes :

```
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("failover:(tcp://host1:5670)");
    cf.setTransportListener(new TransportListener() {
        @Override
        public void transportResumed() {
        }

        @Override
        public void transportInterupted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(IOException error) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCommand(Object command) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried this; my observation is if I pulled the n/w cable from my machine(consumer/subscriber), after 15sec, getting transportInterupped, after that even if I connect the n/w cable nothing happens. (I am not getting any new updates for the topics I subscribed).  the topics are not persisted.

Comment: Certainly if you use a topic without durable subscription. You have to create a durable subscription or use a retroactive consumer http://activemq.apache.org/retroactive-consumer.html

Comment: I am using retroactive consumer, but not a durable subscription.  Should I be using durable subscription as well?  Will that solve my problem of not getting any more updates after my consumer is connected back to n/w?

Comment: Normally retroactive consumer is enough, can you update your question with consumer code and activemq.xml